# What is the "Content-Length" in regards to this URL

Tags: post, amazon-ses

I have a URL and i am trying to create a Amazon SES POST message, and i have come across the httpheader attribute "Content-Length". And i am not sure exactly what it means. Is it the lenght of the whole url, the length of the RawMessage.

Then is it just counting the number of characters? Or something else.

Below is a sample HTTP Post.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1 - Auto
Date: Thu, 26 May 2011 06:49:50 GMT
Host: amazon-email
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=<KEY>, Algorithm=HmacSHA256, Signature=<TBC>
Content-Length: ??

https://email.amazon.com?
Action=SendRawEmail
&Destinations.member.1=test%40example.com
&RawMessage.Data=RnJvbTp1c2VyQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBUZXN0DQoNCk1lc3
```

With this example what is the Conent-Length:

- 58 - Number of characters?

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Length` is the number of bytes in the POST body (after the headers).

Comment: so your saying all of this `https://email.amazon.com?Action=SendRawEmail&Destinations.member.1=test%40example.com&RawMessage.Data=RnJvbTp1c2VyQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBUZXN0DQoNCk1lc3`

Comment: @Keevil: Yes.  Beware of UTF8